# Print value of mapped data

Tags: reactjs

I have a question I'm sure it's something easy but I don't find solution.
I'm mapping an array of objects with objects looking like this:

```
{
   categoryFr: "Commande",
   categoryEn: "Order"
}
```

Now I want to to print this data in a `div` so if I do this, it works I get `Commande`:

```
   <div>{categoryFr}</div>
```

But I want to dynamically render accordingly to the language I tried :

```
  <div>`c.name${lang}`</div>
  <div>`${c.name}${lang}`</div>
```

But the string `categoryFr` is printed instead of the value `Commande`.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is ```<div>{object[`${c.name}${lang}`]}</div>```

Answer (score 0):

you can access it with something like:

```
<div>{c[name + lang]}</div>
```

since `obj.property` (`obj.categoryFr`) is the equivalent with `obj[property]` (`obj["category" + "Fr"]`)